# Сохранение введённых данных текстового поля в исходном коде через Javascript.

Tags: html, javascript

Есть исходный код страницы:

http://jsfiddle.net/u990uzjf/

Далее я выполняю следующие действия:

В текстовое поле `txt` я ввожу текст '777' и нажимаю кнопку 'Сохранить'. После этих действий, у меня перезагружается страница, и в ней должен быть следующий исходный код:

http://jsfiddle.net/u990uzjf/1/

Как видите, в исходном коде сохранился текст '777' в текстовом поле. Как можно это сделать НЕ через PHP, а через Javascript или что-то наподобие этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать, например, `sessionStorage` или `localStorage`.

```
var txt=document.getElementById("txt");
txt.value=sessionStorage["txt"] || "?";
//вызывается при клике на кнопку
window.go=function(){
         sessionStorage["txt"]=txt.value;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q78u3yms/)

[[@Никита___](/users/26009/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0___)](/users/26009/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0___) если нужно изменить страницу на сервере, то без программы, которая там выполняется, не обойтись. На PHP это сделать несложно

```
if(isset($_GET['txt'])){
    file_put_contents("test.html", 
       preg_replace(
          '/(id="txt".*?value=")\K.*?(?=")/s', $_GET['txt'], 
           file_get_contents("test.html")) 
       );
}
echo file_get_contents('test.html');
```

test.html:

```
<form action="">
<input type="text" class="text" id="txt" name="txt" maxlength="5" value="">
<input type="submit" class="text" id="button" value="Сохранить">
</form>
```

Comment: Нет. Я Вам сейчас попробую более подробно объяснить. Пишу в текстовом поле, к примеру, '777' // Нажимаю на кнопку 'Сохранить' // Закрываю файл // Снова открываю файл... и в нём уже должно быть введено '777', т.е. они должны быть прописаны в исходный код.

Comment: @Никита___ изменить исходный код с помощью одного лишь javascript можно только если страница находится на локальной машине, с помощью FileSystem API. Если вам нужно, чтобы значение оставалось всё время, но только для того, кто нажал кнопку «Сохранить», то нужно заменить `sessionStorage` на `localStorage` в моём коде.

Comment: Не совсем. Мне нужно, чтобы любой пользователь мог зайти и изменить это значение для всех. Этот файл в дальнейшем будет в интернете.

Comment: Ну уж если через Javascript нельзя, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать каким-либо другим способом. Но всё же, мне желательно, чтобы это был не PHP))).

Comment: @Никита___ а какие «серверные» языки поддерживает? Ещё раз хочу отметить, что без них, увы, записать что-либо в файл не получится.

Comment: храните все в массиве, в том же json, например... может, у вас на сайте node.js стоит?)

Comment: Короче, всё-таки Ваши ответы таковы: "Через Javascript нельзя сохранять данные". Я верно понимаю?

Comment: @Никита___ «сохранять» в страницу на сервере — нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

На JavaScript ничего не получится. Хранилище есть только в браузере. Куки, sessionStorage, localStorage WebSql
если не хочешь светить реал нэйм можно MD5 записывать туда или свой механизм шифрования. А без php - python, java, perl, ruby, nodJs